# Why passing an empty string on the command line throws an exception?

Tags: java

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Why running it as `java Main ""` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if java allows to initialize String variable with ""?

`String[] args = { "" };`

Comment: Are you providing any arguments to the program when you run it?

Comment: If I run your code with `java Main ""` on my machine it works fine. What operating system is this?

Comment: windows 10, and you?

Comment: @Aym Debian. So I'd say it's either a problem with how cmd (or PowerShell?) handles empty string rather than with java.

Comment: `cmd` seems to drop `""`, try `'""'`.

Comment: (Just noticed there's an extraneous "either" in my previous comment but I can't edit it anymore, so please just ignore it)

Comment: @xehpuk wouldn't that print `""`? I think they're trying to pass an empty string, not two literal `"`.

Comment: I too think its because cmd\powershell doesnt read **""**. I write **>java Main "" A** and it prints **A**. Ty

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I checked again. `""` works fine in `cmd`. In `PS`, it has to be `""""` or `'""'` to yield an empty string.

Comment: This works fine on my Windows10 (in CMD). How are you processing the supplied arg(s) within the `main()` method?